# Запрос и изменение данных из БД sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite3

Проблема,у меня есть база данных sqlite3.
В ней есть столбцы.

```
balance  iduser
      0  (Любой ид)
```

Мне нужно сделать,при вводе команды /изменить баланс (значение баланса)
Изменение моего баланса,но как это сделать?

Comment: 1. Поймать команду 2. Сделать update/insert sql

Comment: cursor.execute(f'UPDATE таблица SET balance=число where iduser=ид пользователя')

Comment: @Merka,а если у меня пишет(name “cursor “ not defined) хотя в первой функции я сделал их глобальными.

Comment: значит, что что то не то) это всё что я могу понять из вашего объяснения